# Architecting a WPF application with WCF Data Services

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, wcf-data-services

Is there any open source project that makes use of both the WPF and WCF Data Services technologies and that is well designed so that one might see how to implement a good app using those two technologies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently many projects that are using the [Netflix OData](http://developer.netflix.com/docs/OData_Catalog) feed. Looking for projects that use that feed would probably be a good place to start.

Karl Shifflett has a an [article](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/stuff-wpf-line-of-business-using-mvvm-video-tutorial/) and series of screencasts on his blog that covers a WPF project that uses WPF, MVVM, the Netflix OData (using WCF DataServices client) and includes a link to the [source code](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=51de981e071f222b&id=51DE981E071F222B!238).